# "Illegal scheme supplied, only alphanumeric characters are permitted" in Magento 1.9.1.0

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, magento-1.9.1

I want to change my admin url from admin section. I went to `System > Configuration > Admin` then set `yes` to `Use Custom Admin URL` and in section `Custom Admin URL` I wrote /administrator/.

Then I click on save button and then I change the admin path from admin to administrator from:

app/etc/local.xml

```
<admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <frontName><![CDATA[administration]]></frontName>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
```

After deleting cache from var/cache folder, it shows the above error when i changed my url to

```
http://localhost/fappystorebk/administration/
```

How can I solve this issue? The error looks like

```
Illegal scheme supplied, only alphanumeric characters are permitted

#0 D:\xampp\htdocs\fappystorebk\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Store.php(777): Zend_Uri::factory('/administration...')
#1 D:\xampp\htdocs\fappystorebk\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Store.php(611): Mage_Core_Model_Store->isCurrentlySecure()
#2 D:\xampp\htdocs\fappystorebk\app\Mage.php(382): Mage_Core_Model_Store->getBaseUrl('skin', NULL)
#3 D:\xampp\htdocs\fappystorebk\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Design\Package.php(349): Mage::getBaseUrl('skin', NULL)
#4 D:\xampp\htdocs\fappystorebk\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Design\Package.php(503): Mage_Core_Model_Design_Package->getSkinBaseUrl(Array)
#5 D:\xampp\htdocs\fappystorebk\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(1035): Mage_Core_Model_Design_Package->getSkinUrl('reset.css', Array)
#6 D:\xampp\htdocs\fappystorebk\app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\login.phtml(32): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getSkinUrl('reset.css')
#7 D:\xampp\htdocs\fappystorebk\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(241): include('D:\\xampp\\htdocs...')
#8 D:\xampp\htdocs\fappystorebk\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml\\defau...')
#9 D:\xampp\htdocs\fappystorebk\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#10 D:\xampp\htdocs\fappystorebk\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#11 D:\xampp\htdocs\fappystorebk\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#12 D:\xampp\htdocs\fappystorebk\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Text\List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#13 D:\xampp\htdocs\fappystorebk\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#14 D:\xampp\htdocs\fappystorebk\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#15 D:\xampp\htdocs\fappystorebk\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#16 D:\xampp\htdocs\fappystorebk\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\controllers\IndexController.php(82): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#17 D:\xampp\htdocs\fappystorebk\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_IndexController->loginAction()
#18 D:\xampp\htdocs\fappystorebk\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('login')
#19 D:\xampp\htdocs\fappystorebk\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#20 D:\xampp\htdocs\fappystorebk\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#21 D:\xampp\htdocs\fappystorebk\app\Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#22 D:\xampp\htdocs\fappystorebk\index.php(88): Mage::run('', 'store')
#23 {main}
```

Answer (score 0):

First roll back your changes :
follow this step to change admin url

1) change path in app/etc/local.xml

```
<admin>
  <routers>
    <adminhtml>
      <args>
        <frontName><![CDATA[administration]]></frontName>
      </args>
    </adminhtml>
  </routers>
</admin>
```

2)  remove cache by remove cache folder
    rm -rf var/cache/*

then Check it.